# Передача аргументов в метод класса наследника

Tags: java, android, ооп

Есть следующие строки написаные на `Java` взяти из `Android SDK`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

В этом примере класс `MainActivity` наследует класс `AppCompatActivity`
и переопределяет метод `onRestoreInstanceState` в который получает объект типа `Bundle`. Этот экземпляр `savedInstanceState` - может содержать в себе какие то данные, т.е. он не `null`.

Вопрос: каким образом реализовываются подобные вещи, в смысле как в переопределенный метод попадает аргумент который в себе уже что то содержит? Или если отвлечься от `Android` и взять чисто `Java` - может ли класс предок в переопределенный метод в классе-наследнике передавать какие то аргументы?

Comment: т.е. в классе от которого наследуются вызвать метод который был переопределен, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да, и передать в него аргументы. На сколько я понимаю что в классе предке этот метод должен быть абстрактным  но в исходниках я вижу уже конкретную реализацию, и не могу опять кто из вышестоящих по иерархии классов вызывает данный метод

Comment: из класса родителя нельзя вызвать переопределенный метод, если он не является абстрактным. В вашем случае метод вызывается у класса потомка, а в этом методе уже дергается метод в классе, который находится выше по иерархии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не переопределенные методы супер-класса, а колбэки (методы обратного вызова), которые реализуются через интерфейс обратного вызова и специально сделаны для того, чтобы передавать события между несвязанными классами.

Наследование от класса `Activity` в данном случае не является источником значения в методе `onRestoreInstanceState()` - значение там появляется по событию создания/пересоздания активити и генерируется системой, передается через интерфейс.

Хорошим тоном считается выделять методы обратного вызова предлогом *on-* (onCreate, onResume ...) - по этому предлогу мы и видим, что здесь колбэк, а не наследование.

Comment: пока что я нашел в исходниках  только     protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) метод класса Activity. Через какой интерфейс осуществляеться вызов onCreate ?

Comment: @KirillStoianov Документация не особо распространяется по этому поводу, ставя перед фактом, что методы жизненного цикла управляются  колбэками, которые генерирует сама система, а мне вот вникать как то лень. Можно с уверенностью сказать, что класс `Activity` глубоко интегрирован в систему и просто принять, что эти колбэки реагируют на события системы. Вам это нужно с определенной целью или из простого любопытства? Дело в том, что ответ на ваш вопрос - нет, родитель не передает и не может передавать аргументы в потомок, здесь работает другой механизм, задействующий системные функции.

Comment: Я понял, в общем все делает система, и в этот метод что то  попадает только если туда кто то что то передаст? Я просто думал что есть какие то Java механизмы о которых я не знал!

Comment: @KirillStoianov Этот механизм - обычный интерфейс обратного вызова (как например листенеры кликов по виджетам - вы переопределяете метод `onClick()` и он получает аргументом `View`, по которой кликнули), только генерирует событие не пользоваельский код, а система, переходя в определенные состояния жизненного цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Из класса родителя нельзя вызвать переопределенный метод, если он не является абстрактным. В вашем случае метод вызывается у класса потомка, а в этом методе уже дергается метод в классе, который находится выше по иерархии.

Answer (score 1):

В java, да и других языках это называется наследование. Когда вы наследуете один класс от другого, а потом создаете экземпляр класса-потомка, он так же является экземпляром класса-родителя, т.е. если вы заходите присвоить переменной-родителю экземпляр класса потомка `Parent parent = new Child()`, то это не будет ошибкой. И если вы вызываете метод, который есть на родителе, то сначала будет произведен поиск на наличие метода с такой же сигнатурой, как и вызываемый у родителя, т.е. метода, переопределяющего метод родителя (Override). При этом добавлять аннотацию @Override не обязательно (как у меня в примере), но является хорошим тоном. Советую почитать вам немного информации о наследовании и ООП в целом. Удачи!

```
class Parent {
  void passArg(String someArg) {
    System.out.println("Вызов в классе-родителе: " + someArg);  
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   void passArg(String someArg) {
      super.passArg(someArg);
      System.out.println("Вызов в классе-потомке: " + someArg);
   }
}

// Где-то в функции main

Parent child = new Child();
child.passArg("Я родился!");

// Вывод будет таким:
// Вызов в классе-родителе: Я родился!
// Вызов в классе-потомке: Я родился!

Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.passArg("Я родился");

// Вывод будет таким:
// Вызов в классе-родителе: Я родился
```

P.S. В примере выше функция родителя срабатывает только потому, что я явно вызываю ее в переопределенной функции на потомке через `super.passArg(someArg)`, передавая туда уже имеющийся аргумент.